# Python: Simple Game of Life Implementation, Checking 2D List's "Neighboring" elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, conways-game-of-life

I am creating a simple Game of Life by Conway in python using 2D lists, and I'm having trouble trying to:

1. Check the 3x3 area around a cell that is alive
2. Count the amount of times another "alive cell" is in the 3x3 Area:

The list that I created goes along something like this:

```
board = [
[".",".",".","O","."],
[".","O","O",".","."],
[".",".","O",".","."],
[".",".",".","O","O"],
[".",".","O","O","."]
]
```

Where a '.' is a dead cell and a 'O' is an alive cell.

I tried using a function where it detects the 8 neighboring areas of an element like this:

```
def checkNeigbors():
    count = 0
    neighbors = [(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, -1), (-1, 1)]
```

the neighbors list given I thought was supposed to be the coordinate for each element so it will detect the x+(neighbor value), y + (neighbor value)

However, at this point, I don't know how to make it so that for each 'O', it needs to count every other instance of 'O' in a 3x3 area and add it to the "count" variable. Do i have to make a for loop trying to read each rows and columns in the board?

Comment: Yes.  You'll have to loop through each Y and each X, and do a "neighbor" count for each cell, and create the new generation state.  REMEMBER not to alter your old state as you create the new one, otherwise your later counts will be wrong.

Comment: you might want to look into numpy arrays and convolutions. It is not an answer to your question, but it will make your life a lot easier